# Can Z3 apply bit-width reduction techniques to solve a bit-vector equivalence?

Tags: z3, smt, theorem-proving

During a [program synthesis task](https://github.com/google/souper/issues/738) I hit the following equivalence, which is based on mixed-boolean-arithmetic logic and that I can't seem to be able to prove with Z3 in a reasonable amount of time (some seconds or minutes). I'm following a counter-example driven approach (CEGIS), feeding the original expression and the synthesis candidate to a **distinct** query: if no counter-examples are found the synthesis is correct.

```
(set-logic QF_BV)
(declare-fun y () (_ BitVec 64))
(declare-fun x () (_ BitVec 64))
(assert (let ((a!1 (bvsub (bvsub (bvsub x #x0000000000000002) y)
                  (bvshl (bvor x (bvnot y)) #x0000000000000001))))
(let ((a!2 (bvmul (bvand (bvxor a!1 x) (bvnot y))
                  (bvand y (bvnot (bvxor a!1 x))))))
(let ((a!3 (bvadd (bvmul (bvor (bvxor a!1 x) y) (bvand (bvxor a!1 x) y)) a!2)))
  (distinct a!3 (bvmul y y))))))
(check-sat)
```

I know the equivalence to hold just fine for reduced bit-width bit-vectors (e.g. 8 or 16), so I was wondering if Z3 is employing any technique to first prove the bit-width reduced version of the query and then extend the result to the full-width version.

I tried the Z3 **bv-size-reduction** tactic, but it doesn't seem to fit my requirements because it's meant to reduce the size of the constants and not of the symbolic bit-vectors. Moreover, the [implementation](https://github.com/martinjonas/bw-reducing-solver) of the **Speeding-up Quantified Bit-Vector Solving Bit-Width Reductions and Extensions** paper doesn't seem to work out for this specific case, because no useful counter-model is generated, keeping the size of the problem unaltered.

I'm not a SAT/SMT person, as I barely use tools like Z3 as black boxes to play around with synthesis problems, so I was wondering:

- Is there anything I can do to reduce the bit-width of the bit-vectors, prove the reduced query and extend the results to the full-width query?
- Is there any other viable way to prove the unsatisfiability of the aforementioned query?

Comment: This is an excellent question. Unfortunately, I don't think z3 implements these techniques, nor there's anything out-of-the box you can use so far as I know. You might want to ping z3 developers at https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues to see if they have any other recommendations.

Comment: Thanks @alias for the comment. I purposefully avoided to open a GitHub issue for now because, on other issues, the Z3 developers pointed out that Stack Overflow should be the right place for these kind of questions. I'll wait to see if someone has any recommendations, even non out-of-the-box approaches or a custom pipeline of tactics, that I'll be able to try on my own. As a last resort I'll open a GitHub issue either on the bw-reducing-solver repository or on the Z3 repository.